Error from git during push, but still pushes successfully?
In ADO with a YML pipeline, in a PowerShell task, on a MSFT hosted agent, I am running these commands, to initialize a folder with files, and push it to an existing (empty) repository in ADO.
> git init --initial-branch=main
> git config user.email "xxx"
> git config user.name  "xxx"
> git add *
> git commit -m "xxx"
> git remote add origin https://$pat@xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/$project/_git/$repository
> git push -u origin main

The error I am getting is ##[error]To ( see image )
branch 'main' set up to track 'origin/main'.
##[error]To https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/xxx/_git/xxx
 * [new branch]      main -> main

The commands run, but it looks like the "git push" throws an error. But it DOES UPLOAD THE FILES SUCCESSFULLY. I am unsure what the error is, pretty hard to google it, without any actual error description or keywords. It does however fail my pipeline. I am unsure if this happens from a non-0 exit code, or something being written to err-out.
What's the issue? What am I doing wrong? Or what can I do, for this to not fail my pipeline.
